# XSLT 1.0 sorting by child elements value

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have tried around with this for far too long, but I am not getting my data sorted correctly. Basically I want to sort all my collectedKeys under the root element by their keyId. All other information should go unchanged into the output.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <base>
        <id>a</id>
        <name>b</name>
        <subId>c</subId>
    </base>
    <key>lvl1</key>
    <key>lvl3</key>
    <collectedKeys>
        <keyInformation>
            <keyId>100</keyId>
            <content>
                <contentID>4</contentID>
            </content>
            <keyStatus>40001</keyStatus>
            <initLang>false</initLang>
        </keyInformation>
    </collectedKeys>
    <collectedKeys>
        <keyInformation>
            <keyId>200</keyId>
            <content>
                <contentID>4</contentID>
            </content>
            <keyStatus>40002</keyStatus>
            <initLang>false</initLang>
        </keyInformation>
    </collectedKeys>
    <collectedKeys>
        <keyInformation>
            <keyId>100</keyId>
            <content>
                <contentID>4</contentID>
            </content>
            <keyStatus>40003</keyStatus>
            <initLang>false</initLang>
        </keyInformation>
    </collectedKeys>
    <collectedKeys>
        <keyInformation>
            <keyId>300</keyId>
            <content>
                <contentID>4</contentID>
            </content>
            <keyStatus>40004</keyStatus>
            <initLang>false</initLang>
        </keyInformation>
    </collectedKeys>
    <additionalKeys>50</additionalKeys>
    <additionalKeys>70</additionalKeys>
    <ignoredKeys>
        <keyInformation>
            <keyId>500</keyId>
            <content>
                <contentID>3</contentID>
            </content>
            <keyStatus>60001</keyStatus>
            <initLang>true</initLang>
        </keyInformation>
    </ignoredKeys>
    <ignoredKeys>
        <keyInformation>
            <keyId>600</keyId>
            <content>
                <contentID>1</contentID>
            </content>
            <keyStatus>50001</keyStatus>
            <initLang>false</initLang>
        </keyInformation>
    </ignoredKeys>
</root>
```

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <base>
        <id>a</id>
        <name>b</name>
        <subId>c</subId>
    </base>
    <key>lvl1</key>
    <key>lvl3</key>
    <collectedKeys>
        <keyInformation>
            <keyId>100</keyId>
            <content>
                <contentID>4</contentID>
            </content>
            <keyStatus>40001</keyStatus>
            <initLang>false</initLang>
        </keyInformation>
    </collectedKeys>
    <collectedKeys>
        <keyInformation>
            <keyId>100</keyId>
            <content>
                <contentID>4</contentID>
            </content>
            <keyStatus>40003</keyStatus>
            <initLang>false</initLang>
        </keyInformation>
    </collectedKeys>
    <collectedKeys>
        <keyInformation>
            <keyId>200</keyId>
            <content>
                <contentID>4</contentID>
            </content>
            <keyStatus>40002</keyStatus>
            <initLang>false</initLang>
        </keyInformation>
    </collectedKeys>
    <collectedKeys>
        <keyInformation>
            <keyId>300</keyId>
            <content>
                <contentID>4</contentID>
            </content>
            <keyStatus>40004</keyStatus>
            <initLang>false</initLang>
        </keyInformation>
    </collectedKeys>
    <additionalKeys>50</additionalKeys>
    <additionalKeys>70</additionalKeys>
    <ignoredKeys>
        <keyInformation>
            <keyId>500</keyId>
            <content>
                <contentID>3</contentID>
            </content>
            <keyStatus>60001</keyStatus>
            <initLang>true</initLang>
        </keyInformation>
    </ignoredKeys>
    <ignoredKeys>
        <keyInformation>
            <keyId>600</keyId>
            <content>
                <contentID>1</contentID>
            </content>
            <keyStatus>50001</keyStatus>
            <initLang>false</initLang>
        </keyInformation>
    </ignoredKeys>
</root>
```

Unfortunately my current xslt is not doing the sorting and I cannot figure out why not.

This is the XLST I am using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
<!--                                                --> 
  <xsl:template match="collectedKeys">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="keyInformation">
        <xsl:sort select="keyId" data-type="number"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the `collectedKeys` nodes, you must do so when you apply templates to them - not to their children. Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="base | key"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="collectedKeys">
            <xsl:sort select="keyInformation/keyId" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="additionalKeys | ignoredKeys"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```